# Best practices writing unit tests with NHibernate

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to NHibernate (+Fluent), and I can't decide on what's the best strategy when it comes to structuring my code to make it testable. I have a plain structure including a domain model, mappings to map the model to database, and a few classes with behavior which will work towards the model classes and do transactions for updating and reading out data from the database. I have more on top of this, but that's not relevant here.

Now, when it comes to the unit testing what seems natural to me is to inject *something* to the behavior classes such that they will get a SQLite database for testing, or the real database however this is configured. Does this make sense? What I can't decide is **what** to inject.

- I could inject the ISession, but I assume I'd want to use new sessions for each - well - session? If so I'd need something outside to create the sessions, which might just move the problem?
- Could I inject the SessionSource? In this case the behavior classes could create sessions themselves using this. However, I see the SessionSource is used to BuildSchema - something I assume I only want to do once?
- The third option I see - and what I've done this far - is to create a SessionFactory which creates a session for me. Using this I can add a using-clause and have the session disposed when the function finishes. I have a SessionFactory-interface and a regular and a unittest implementation. Injecting either the regular or unittest implementation I get a session for the right database.

Am I on the right track? How should I strcuture my code for writing unit tests for code using NHibernate? Any best practices I should be aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to check out this blog post by Ayende:
[Nhibernate Unit Testing](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/28/nhibernate-unit-testing.aspx). He has a test base class that configures the session with an in memory database (sql lite). This seems be similar to your third option.